# Why is data stored on a Samsung SSD corrupted twice after unplugging?

Tags: ssd, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption, samsung-ssd

I have a single computer and two Windows OS's, each on its own SSD. Once in a while, I power down computer and swap SSDs to boot into another system. This is because I want these OSes isolated from each other (one of them is low-security sandbox).

I do it this way:

1. Use normal shutdown in Windows
2. open computer case's lid
3. wait for CPU fan to stop (fan is right near the cable, so it's hard to make a mistake here)
4. reconnect SATA and power cables

Two times already, after swapping back, I find lots of file corruption on SSD. Corrupted files include:

- various read-only files, such as system partition's boot files, Windows system files, etc.
- My own files I'm actively working with
- My own files I haven't touched for a couple years

That is, it doesn't look to be some kind of "write wasn't flushed properly". Rather, it's about seemingly random corruption of around 1% of disk clusters.

The Windows that is on Samsung SSD corrupted twice already (on two different Samsung SSDs). The other Windows is on Kingston SSD and never experiences any troubles after swapping.

Corrupted Samsung Disks are:

- Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB
- Samsung SSD 870 EVO 4TB

Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB corrupted today, and it has newest firmware `RVT04B6Q`.

Its current SMART counters are

```
Model Name, Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB
Result,ID,Description,Threshold,Current Value,Worst Value,Raw Data
,5,Reallocated Sector Count,10,100,100,0,OK
,9,Power-on Hours,0,97,97,10616,OK
,12,Power-on Count,0,97,97,2463,OK
,177,Wear Leveling Count,0,99,99,16,OK
,179,Used Reserved Block Count (total),10,100,100,0,OK
,181,Program Fail Count (total),10,100,100,0,OK
,182,Erase Fail Count (total),10,100,100,0,OK
,183,Runtime Bad Count (total),10,100,100,0,OK
,187,Uncorrectable Error Count,0,100,100,0,OK
,190,Airflow Temperature,0,60,38,40,OK
,195,ECC Error Rate,0,200,200,0,OK
,199,CRC Error Count,0,100,100,0,OK
,235,POR Recovery Count,0,99,99,437,OK
,241,Total LBAs Written,0,99,99,27696253985,OK
```

What catches my eye here is `POR Recovery Count` (explained as "sudden power off cases"). So far I swapped disks maybe 30 times max, very far from 437.

Can someone explain why data gets corrupted?

**Update 1**
I don't think it's SATA cable, because:

1. Other Windows would also have problems then
2. After disk was corrupted, I ran full Samsung Magician test on it, and it went clean. With a faulty cable, I wouldn't expect that.
3. Checked Windows Event Log, no 'Disk' errors logged.
4. Data only corrupted after swapping disks, not while staying on one disk (I stay on one disk for weeks or months, and only swap to other disk seldomly)

**Update 2**
Tried to figure what causes `POR Recovery Count`:

- Windows reboot - no increase
- Windows shutdown and boot - no increase
- Swapped SSDs, some 5 minutes later swapped back - no increase

That is, I didn't find what's causing them.

**Update 3**
Has been swapping disks almost every day in the last 30 days. Still using the same SATA cable. However, I no longer disconnect power cable from the other drive (both are powered at all times, but only one has SATA cable). No corruption so far.

Comment: Do you use a hotswap bay of some kind or do you just connect the regular SATA cables? The SATA connectors weren't originally designed for constant (re) connections, and especially if it's just cables being swapped around then I'd be suspicious of those already failing....

Comment: Edit: swapping SATA cable. Also see Update1 at the end.

Comment: Fans and SSD may be using different connections to power supply, and there might be a capacitor in the SSD holding a charge to finish up any pending operation on shutdown. Test by waiting *a few minutes* before swapping.

Comment: I don't exactly understand capacitor idea. If the capacitor is inside SSD, does it matter if it's connected to shut down motherboard? Also, does that mean that sudden wall socket power loss would corrupt data in SSD?

Comment: Not all SSDs have supercaps as means for power-loss-protection. It's typically something you'd find at enterprise class SSDs.

Comment: All of the above are helpful suggestions but I would start with the basic: Disable Fast Startup in both.

Comment: POR Recovery Count is [explained](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/resources/others/SSD_Application_Note_SMART_final.pdf) by Samsung as: "A count of the number of sudden power off cases. If there is a sudden power off, the firmware must recover all of the mapping and user data **during the next power on**. This is a count of the number of times this has happened." I suggest waiting *several minutes* after the computer's power-down and before disconnecting power to the Samsung disk. I second disabling Fast Startup on both disks. Can't you use multi-boot instead of cutting power?

Comment: "I wait for CPU fan to stop before swapping" Do I read you right that you just perform a normal shutdown before that, without disconnecting the mains cable or switching off the PSU ?

Comment: "I expect an answer that would be supported by something better than pure guesses" : You downvoted my answer on the ground that it's just a guess, yet your Update 3 fully supports my guess, although I don't have any official internal documentation to support it.

Comment: > you just perform a normal shutdown before that, without disconnecting the mains cable or switching off the PSU ?

Yes.

Comment: There's your problem: the power is still live to the motherboard

Comment: @Codeguard: I see that several other answers have come up which build upon my explanation of the way that Samsung SSD depends on continuous power after the OS shutdown for an orderly firmware shutdown. None of them are supported by any sort of documentation, all are equally guesses. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

So, you shut down your OS, open the case and start disconnecting cables.

What you need to know is that **a system shutdown does not mean power is disconnected !** How PC's have been built in the last 28 years or so ([ATX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX) was patented in 1995), the so-called "power" button only sends an impulse to the mainboard, which is interpreted according to the current state: If the OS is shut down, the Bios will initialize. If it is sleeping, it will resume. If it's powered on it might go to sleep etc. Accordingly, even if the OS is powered down, the Power Supply Unit (PSU) will continue to provide a +5VSB standby current [which is always on](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/101295-sleep-mode-does-psu-power-down.html) ([second source](https://silentpcreview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=26925) - and see the above link on ATX), unless you **physically flip the circuit breaker of your PSU** (usually located at the back of a case). Also, once the BIOS has sent the signal to the PSU to switch to VSB current only, the [capacitors in the PSU](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/power-supplies-101,4193-3.html) (needed to convert AC power to DC, but also to provide a stable power output) are still full, and will cause a difference of potential between Ground and Voltage connectors on your whole system. This can endure for minutes, unless you flip the circuit breaker. Also, the ATX specs do not specify how fast a PSU must turn off, so it might stay on if some components are still drawing current.

So, **after a system shutdown, your mainboard is still receiving power** and components can receive still current for several minutes. If you just disconnected the cables from your disks, you could easily have fried them completely, or **you could have even damaged your mainboard**.

A [SATA power cable](https://www.lifewire.com/sata-15-pin-power-connector-pinout-2624584) has pins for 3.3 VDC, 5 VDC, 12 VDC and 6 Grounds Connectors. The connectors are made in a way that when you are connecting or disconnecting them under current, **there's a high probability that the grounds are disconnected while one or more of the power pins are connected. This will send a shock to your electronics** against which it is not protected, so it may cause any kind of damage, depending on how the component is manufactured. On your Samsung Disk, it was enough for some stray electrons to wind up in the wrong place, in order to cause corruption. But it's also possible that some sectors simply got fried.

Consumer disks have some protection against electrostatic shocks, but they are not protected against power shocks: only disks which support hot-swapping usually have such protection.

The same thing - although less likely - can even happen on a SATA Data connection, sending an electric shock towards your mainboard, too. It's not something you'd  want to risk. It can go well 100 times, but once is enough to fry something.

### The only safe way to service any of your PC's electronics:

- shut down the OS
- wait a minute or so
- flip the circuit breaker on your PSU to the OFF position, or if there is none (very rare!), disconnect the mains cable and wait a few minutes
- disconnect any peripherals that are in standby (Monitors) as their cables can still transmit current
- wait some minutes to let stray charges disspate
- If you are 100% sure you won't be touching anything but plastic components, you can now risk to open your case, **BUT:**
- Any skilled service technician will disconnect the mains and all other cables from the case, and place the whole case on a grounded antistatic mat, letting it sit there for a moment to get rid of static electricity. He will place all his tools onto the same mat and be sure to be touching it himself, before opening the case.

Anything short of the above is bound to shorten the life of your electronics.

### But why only the Samsung SSD ?

No way to know. Any combination of

- how  the drives are built
- which one you disconnect first
- sheer luck

### And how about the POR Recovery count ?

It's at roughly 18% of Power-on counts, so this just **does not fit your description of how many times you swapped disks**. Also, POR Recovery Count has the same 99 (out of 100 initial) rating as the total LBAs written. Furthermore, [Samsung's Description](https://download.semiconductor.samsung.com/resources/others/SSD_Application_Note_SMART_final.pdf) doesn't hint to something which could loose data written to the disk. So it looks like a general wear metric. There really is no detailed info on this online.

### What I would do

Virtually all BIOS/UEFI implementations allow you to change the sequence of boot disks. So I'd possibly avoid to touch the physical connections, but just boot into BIOS and change the setting. It's faster and safer.

### EDITS

1. SATA Disks should by their specs support hot plug, but hot disconnect is still something different. Also, most mainboards DON'T support hot plug: it could fry your mainboard, as [someone found out the hard way](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?t=45566). There are specific hot-plug bays to use SATA for hot plugging. The SATA cables present in most systems also are not made for continuos plug-in or plug-out.
2. If measuring on the SATA Cable with a multimeter, you should measure during shutdown, on all combinations of voltage and ground pins to be sure current goes off immediately after shutdown. Also, voltage might differ between shutdowns, depending on how long the system was up and what the disk was doing just before shutdown. It's just not something to risk.
3. The type of corruption which you experience points towards a physical defect on the disk, and not something which would happen while the system is up. This supports the present answer.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed reply! I disconnect the disk's cable because it contains low-security OS which must be reliably isolated from accessing other OS's files. However, it's not THAT low security that I would be afraid of firmware overwrites/etc.

Comment: Regarding "you could have fried": I thought that SATA supports hot plug, can you clarify?

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not correct. I took a multimeter and found that 1) When OS is shut down, there's no power on SATA and 2) Pulling cable from wall socket also brings SATA to 0v in a couple seconds (most likely a lot faster, it's just how quickly my voltmeter can measure it).

Comment: @Codeguard SATA CAN support hot plug, but hot disconnect is still something different. Also, most mainboards DON'T support hot plug: it could fry your mainboard, as [someone found out the hard way](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?t=45566).

Comment: @Codeguard if measuring with a multimeter, you should measure during shutdown, on all combinations of voltage and ground pins to be sure current goes off immediately after shutdown. Also, voltage might differ between shutdowns, depending on how long the system was up and what the disk was doing just before shutdown. It's just not something to risk.

Comment: @Codeguard also see Edit point 3